# Stored procedure / SYS_RefCursor - wrong number of arguments

Tags: oracle, c#-4.0

Given that I have this Oracle stored procedure (it's a test example)

```
PROCEDURE dave IS
dave_data SYS_REFCURSOR;
v_col1 NUMBER;
v_col2 VARCHAr2(100);
BEGIN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE(2000000);
 dave_truck_ticket.get_report_data(dave_data,1234,'01-JUL-13','15-Jul-13');
 LOOP
    FETCH dave_data INTO v_col1, v_col2;
    EXIT WHEN dave_data%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_col1||'   -  '||v_col2);
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE dave_data;
END;
```

And YES the error just might be in the stored procedure - as I've never touched Oracle before..

I'm trying to read the data from the cursor (dave_data) in this manner:

```
  O.OracleConnection objConn = new O.OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=XXXDEV.WORLD;USER ID=XXXXXX;PASSWORD=XXXXXX;");

  O.OracleCommand objCmd = new O.OracleCommand();

  objCmd.Connection = objConn;

  objCmd.CommandText = "DAVE";

  objCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

  O.OracleParameter cursor = new O.OracleParameter("dave_data", O.OracleDbType.RefCursor);
  cursor.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

  objCmd.Parameters.Add(cursor);

  try
  {

    objConn.Open();

    O.OracleDataReader objReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader();
    objReader.Read();
    objReader[0].ToString();
```

My O. reference is specified as:
using O = Oracle.DataAccess.Client; (version 4.112.3.0)

The error I receive (directly after ExecuteReader()) is: 
[image: Oracle error]

What is even more infuriating is that I can execute the example from the Server Explorer - and it works just fine!

Please be kind and point out where I'm being a nob....

Comment: Your proc is messed up.  You need to have the ref cursor as a parameter to the proc, and just open it. No need to do any loop/fetch.  That is what your client code would be doing.  Here is a link (no C# tho) - http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php

Comment: Why aren't you calling `get_report_data` directly? What's the point of the wrapper procedure?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Oracle procedure, and not the C# code.  I received the Oracle procedure from another developer, and we got our wires crossed.  Once he created a OUT parameter with a reference cursor, it worked just fine. +1 to OldProgrammer - you should have made your comment the answer!